# "Inner matrix dimensions must agree" - but it shouldn't be a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions

The following is a snippet from a function I am defining:

```
function [V1, V2] = lambert(R1, R2, t, string)

r1 = norm(R1);
r2 = norm(R2);

z = -100;
while F(z,t) < 0
    z = z + 0.1;
end

tol = 1.e-8;
nmax = 5000;
ratio = 1;
n = 0;

while (abs(ratio) > tol) & (n <= nmax)
    n = n + 1;
    ratio = F(z,t)/dFdz(z);
    z = z - ratio;
end

f = 1 - y(z)/r1;
g = A*sqrt(y(z)/mu);
gdot = 1 - y(z)/r2;

V1 = (R2-f*R1)/g;
V2 = (gdot*R1-R1)/g;

function dum = y(z)
    dum = r1 + r2 + A*(z*S(z) - 1)/sqrt(C(z));
end
```

When I run this code with some vectors `R1`, `R2`, I get:

> Error using `*`.
>   Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

This occurs at these lines:

```
V1 = (R2-f*R1)/g;
V2 = (gdot*R1-R1)/g;
```

I think this is due to the fact that `f` and `gdot` and `g` are matrices whose dimensions are incompatible with `R1` and `R2`. However, as I have defined them, they should simply be scalars. I do not understand what in the code causes them to be matrices.

I've tried using `.*` instead of `*` etc, but with no success.

Comment: Everything in MATLAB is s matrix. And `*` is a matrix multiplicaron. If `R1` and `R2` are the same size (say both are 10x1) then you need to use `.*` instead of `*` to do the element-wise multiplication. Otherwise use `dot` or `cross` for the right type of vector multiplication.

Comment: Put some breakpoints in. Examine the values in various variables as you progress through the code. Should help pinpoint where something stops being scalar. Without knowing what `F`, `A`, `mu` etc are, we can't do this for you.

Comment: Please provide a sample of all input arguments that you're using to run your code that produces that error.  Please see [MCVE]